# refactor a method with a block that contains multiple blocks itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, block

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2

I have a class method called search that takes a block

e.g.

```
class MyClass
  def self.search do
    if criteria1
      keywords "abcde", fields: :c1 do
        minimum_match(1)
      end
    end

    if criteria2
      keywords "defghi", fields: :c2 do
        minimum_match(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What I'd like to do is refactor the MyClass.search method and have a simple one-line method for each if/end statement

e.g. it would look something like this:

```
class MyClass

  def self.search do
    c1_method
    c2_method
  end

  def self.c1_method
    if criteria1
      return keywords "abcde", fields: :c1 do
        minimum_match(1)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.c2_method
    if criteria2
      return keywords "defghi", fields: :c2 do
        minimum_match(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But the refactoring that I show above doesn't quite work.  It looks like the "blocks" that I'm returning in c1_method and c2_method aren't really being returned and evaluated in the search method, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Where are criteria1 and criteria2 defined?

Comment: criteria1 and criteria2 aren't really critical.  they could be anything (e.g. if Time.new.year > 2010).

Comment: Actually i'm unclear as to what c1_method and c2_method are intended to do.  Do they return sets of objects that then need to be merged?  Are the criteria mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the `method(sym)` call in order to get at the body of a method.

```
>> def foo(bar); bar * 2; end
=> nil
>> def baz(bleep); method(:foo).call(bleep); end
=> nil
>> baz(6)
=> 12
```